# Display a UIView without a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a custom UIView that can be displayed at any point in the game. In other words, the UIView is not tied to a specific UIViewController.

Right now my solution is to store a UIViewController* in my custom UIView, set it whenever the UIViewController I'm using changes, and then adding the UIView as a subview of the controller.

I figure there has to be a better, and safer, way of handling this, but I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious - are you trying to make some kind of banner?

Comment: yes, if you're not using the UIViewController, do not create it!

Comment: Yeah, it's a banner of sorts. Something that is separate from the screen it actually shows up on, because it can (theoretically) show up on any screen in the app. My goal is to have it entirely separate from the view controllers so that I don't have to worry about it being added to every single one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a UIView subclass.  File > New File > Objective-C Class > (subclass of ) UIView > Give it a Class Name.

So now you should have something like MyCustomView.h and .m

In the View Controller that you want to display the custom view import the header file

```
#import "MyCustomView.h"
```

Then simply add it to your current view

```
MyCustomView *myCView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:<Where You Want It>];
[self.view addSubview:myCView];
[myCView release];
```

You can use Interface Builder to graphically lay out the custom view.  Or you can do it programmatically.  If you're going the IB way, create a new file, click on User Interface, and View.  Give it the same Class Name i.e. (MyCustomView).

Select the File Owner show the Identity Inspector (option command 3).
For Class, change it from NSObject to MyCustomView.

Comment: I've already got all of that working, the issue is that I'm trying to avoid adding it to another view or view controller. I just want to draw the view straight to the screen.

Comment: Then you should add it to the window or root view controller and then use Z ordering to make sure it is in front of any other view.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I could just add it to the window.

Of course... now it shows up sideways on the side of the screen, but that should be easy enough to fix.

Thanks